# Hibernate: Could not obtain connection to query metadata

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I'm following `Amigoscode` tutorial `Getting Started with Spring Boot` and I'm currently trying to connect to my local database, but I get an error:

> HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata

What I've learned is that Hibernate recent version works different, so the tutorial content it out of data. So I was wondering, can use a older version of Hibernate?

I can also be totally wrong about Hibernate. If this is a command error plz give me some information.

---

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/student
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=******
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.java.show-sql=true   
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PosterSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

NEW ERROR

```
49.203 ERROR 9572 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2022-04-06 11:39:49.203  WARN 9572 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
```

Comment: Can you show me `hibernate configuration` file?

Comment: I edit the post

Comment: You can add `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false`. Also I wouldn't suggest to use `create-drop` unless this is some toy project.

Comment: I added the line to the hibernate config file. Running my code result in an error and warning, that fails to initialize EntityManagerFactory.  What I learned so far is that I must setup this EnityMangerFacroy with persistence.xml etc. That are a lot of extra steps or can I do without an EntityManagerFactory?

See error in original post

Answer (score 1):

There is no meaning of `PosterSQLDialect` in configuration of hibernate dialect. It should be [*PostgreSQLDialect*](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-jpa-hibernate-postgresql-restful-crud-api-example/).

Change

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PosterSQLDialect
```

To

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Comment: I don't get the error anymore, but the warning about the entityManagerFactory remains. I looked around the internet, but I don't get this entityManagerFactory concept. I really don't know how to frame this question for know. But if you can point me in the right direction, that would help a lot.

Comment: @FlyingNimbus Either you don't know how to ask question or your question is not matched with your orignal problem. Show that code in your question where problem is.

Comment: plz take a look at my code: https://github.com/LucasHartman/TestCode
I'm trying to find out how I can connect to my database, do I need EntityManagerFactory for that?